# How to find all fonts paths on Windows

Tags: winapi

I want to find all paths that contain font files that are installed on a Windows 10 system. Traditionally, fonts are installed in `C:\Windows\Fonts` but apparently, they can also be installed in different directories.

Specifically, I got a report from a user who has installed the font `Albertus Extra Bold` on Windows 10. When he opens `C:\Windows\Fonts` in Explorer, selects `Albertus Extra Bold` and chooses "Properties" from the context menu, the dialog shows that the *.ttf file of the font apparently is not installed in `C:\Windows\Fonts` but in `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

So should my app simply scan `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` on top of `C:\Windows\Fonts` or can there be more paths that can contain fonts on Windows 10?

Comment: Fonts can be installed from anywhere. Check the Registry for registered paths: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`. See [Font Installation and Deletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/font-installation-and-deletion) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that registry key is indeed useful. Still, I'm wondering what's going on on the user's system who reported this. Whenever he installs a font, it doesn't end up in `C:\Windows\Fonts` but in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`. Any idea how this can happen? When I install the same font, it ends up in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. On his system, it ends up in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`. Maybe it's a permissions issue?!

Comment: Is the user running with admin privileges? `C:\Windows` is a system folder, only admins should be writing things inside of it. How is the user installing the font exactly?

Comment: He installed it by double-clicking the *.ttf file and then clicking on "Install". I've figured it out now. It seems to be a Windows 10 thing... see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out: It seems to be a Windows 10 thing. When I double-click a *.ttf file on my Windows 7 system and click on "Install", the font will be installed in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. On Windows 10, however, doing the same will lead to the font being installed in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`. So it seems Windows 10 uses non-system folders to avoid requesting admin privileges from the user.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of fonts:

1. System fonts are in `%windir%\Fonts`.
2. User fonts are in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`
3. Temporary fonts can be anywhere in your pc. You add add one by calling [AddFontResourceW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew)

If you are looking for a way to know all the font filename that you have currently, you need to use [DirectWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/introducing-directwrite)

If you are looking to an implementation, you can see how the python library [FindSystemFontsFilename](https://github.com/moi15moi/FindSystemFontsFilename) did it.